# Fielderror.jsp tag is not found during rendering

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I want to use `fieldError` in my jsp.
I am including with `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>`
I am able to write `<s:fieldError>` in jsp, but when try to render it, I receive exception.

```
File /jsp/struts/fielderror.js not found - Class: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
File: JspServlet.java 

<sec:field key="Address.Firstname">
 <label for="NewAccountFirstName">${keyValue}: *</label>
 <sec:highlightedText condition="${fn:contains(normalizedInvoiceAddressFields, 'firstName')}" tagName="span" includeTagIfConditionFalse="false">
 <input id="NewAccountFirstName" name="cf.completeCustomer.invoiceAddress.firstName" type="text" maxlength="40" required="required" value="<c:out value='${cf.completeCustomer.invoiceAddress.firstName}'/>"/>
</sec:highlightedText>
<s:fielderror fieldName="cf.completeCustomer.invoiceAddress.firstName" />
 </sec:field>
```

Comment: Problem is, that it cannot render fielderror.jsp. I can create my own fielderror.jsp but than I do not have expected behaviour. But if I could see how it shall look like, it could fix my troubles.

Comment: Do you have `struts.xml` or `struts.properties`?

Comment: `fielderror.js` != `fielderror.jsp`.